# How to propagate Nom fail context out of many0?

Tags: rust, parser-combinators, nom

I have a Nom parser that parses strings but fails on keywords.

The parser below correctly fails when given a keyword.

But the error message that says it failed because it encountered a keyword does not propagate.

The problem is that while `label` fails, `many0(label)` succeeds with one less result. Subsequently, `eof` fails because not everything was parsed. This correctly fails, but the error message is lost.

How do I propagate the local error message?

*(See below code on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=470b00dad0a58dc9249936d01626869b).)*

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::{take_while, take_while1};
use nom::error::{VerboseError};
use nom::multi::{many0};
use nom::{IResult};
use nom::error::{context};
use nom::combinator::{eof, fail};

type ParseResult<'input, Out> = IResult<&'input str, Out, VerboseError<&'input str>>;

fn label(s1: &str) -> ParseResult<&str> {
    let (s2, a) = take_while1(|c: char| c.is_alphabetic())(s1)?;
    let (s3, _) = take_while(|c: char| c.is_whitespace())(s2)?;
    if a == "derp" {
        return context("this message is lost", fail)(s1);
    }
    Ok((s3, a))
}

fn parse(s: &str) -> ParseResult<Vec<&str>> {
    let (s, labels) = many0(label)(s)?;
    let (s, _) = eof(s)?;
    Ok((s, labels))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse("foo bar herp flerp"));
    // Ok(("", ["foo", "bar", "herp", "flerp"]))

    // This fails with Nom(Eof), both Nom(Fail) and context is lost
    println!("{:?}", parse("foo bar herp derp"));
    // Err(Error(VerboseError { errors: [("derp", Nom(Eof))] }))
}
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=40c6fe511848d1e937b3100c307d70f9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/combinator/fn.cut.html) to prevent `many0` to explore alternatives (consuming less) in the failure case:

```rust
use nom::combinator::cut;
return cut(context("this message is lost", fail))(s1);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=86c608bdced2e09943195cd4af5ae118)

Comment: Wow, amazing! I was literally thinking "something in the lines of Prolog's `cut`...", and there it is.

Comment: After modifying my parser with the use of `cut`, I should add a warning: You can only use `cut` when you're absolutely sure that there's no recourse. In the context of my label checking, labels occur in two ways, as "`<label>:`" and as "`call <label>`". Because my parser is actually `many0(alt((label, instruction)))`, the alternative in the first of these cases is to parse an instruction, I cannot `cut` before I've seen the `:`. In the second case, "`call`" disambiguates sufficiently. Languages like Prolog warn against using `cut` when you can avoid it, because it makes some reasoning harder.

Comment: @sshine cut is not supposed to be use like that but some use it that way, https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/issues/1527, thus I do not recommend it